# Spring Integration Chain Exception Handling with Header enricher inside chain

Tags: spring-integration

I have a common flow that will be reused multiple times. So, I defined a SI Chain for it like below.

```
<int:chain id="addInfo" input-channel="addInfoChannel">
  <int:header-enricher>
     <int:header name="outgoingService" value="Retrieve" />
  </int:header-enricher>      
  <int:gateway request-channel="common_Retrieve_Channel" />
  <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-templates="addInfoXslTemplate">
     <int-xml:xslt-param name="param1" expression="headers.param1" />
     <int-xml:xslt-param name="param2" expression="headers.param2" />
  </int-xml:xslt-transformer>      
  <int:header-enricher>
     <int:header name="outgoingService" value="Add" overwrite="true" />
  </int:header-enricher>
  <int:gateway request-channel="common_Add_Channel" />
</int:chain>
```

If the **common_Retrieve_Channel** channel fails with a SOAP fault, the header value (outgoingService) is lost.
If I have the header-enricher outside the chain, then header value is available on payload.failedMessage.headers.
I don't want to add this value outside chain, Since this value will be changing inside the chain to call another service.

This chain will be called multiple times by setting up the header values (param1 and param2) differently.

Please let me know if there is any better solution other than extracting the gateway into it's own chain. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some *compensation* flow on the `error-channel` of your `<gateway>`.

Since you say that you have SOAP error and you already are familiar with the `payload.failedMessage.headers` you just need to write something like this there:

```
<int:transformer input-channel="gatewayErrorChannel" expression="payload.failedMessage"/>
```

And looks like you further `<chain>` flow should be the same. Only difference that you will get deal there with `requestMessage` only, but lose error information from the external SOAP request.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to stop proceeding with the flow in the chain if an error occurs. I am calling the above chain using gateway  like below and the errorChannel don't have header values that are set inside the chain.  <int:gateway id="parent_AddInfo" request-channel="addInfoChannel" error-channel="parentAddInfoErroChannel" />
   <int:gateway id="child_AddInfo" request-channel="addInfoChannel" error-channel="childAddInfoErroChannel" />

Comment: Well. You must fight a bit with `ErrorMessage` and that `failedMessage` to merge their `headers` properly.

Comment: Header values are not present on payload.failedMessage.headers if an error occurs in the chain. Is there any other way that I can get the header values?

Comment: That's correct because the `failedMessage` is an **incoming** message for the `<chain>` and it really doesn't know anything about the chain logic. You can move those headers definition outside of chain, e.g. to the `<gateway>` declaration...

Comment: Thanks much for the quick responses. I prefer not to specify the header value - "outgoingService" outside the chain since this value will change within the chain each time when it calls different outgoing service. When error occurs errorChannel have to know the value of "outgoing service" to apply logic based on the service.

Comment: A `errorHandler` on the `error-channel` for the ` <int:gateway request-channel="common_Retrieve_Channel" />` will no that `outgoingService` header. Just because its `requestMessage` is that which is the result of the `<header-enricher>` upstream.

Comment: I added 'error-channel' for common-retrieve-channel` and defined errorChannel like below. However, now after processing the error channel flow, it goes back to the chain to process next steps, which I don't want to occur. Is there a way to exit the chain when an error occurs without using any filters. `<int:chain input-channel="addInfoErrorChannel">
      <int:header-enricher><int:header name="error" value="true" />  </int:header-enricher>
      <int:gateway request-channel="service_common_exceptionChannel" />
   </int:chain>`